# Reset ipython kernel

Tags: python, kernel, ipython, reload

I was wondering if there is a way to restart the ipython kernel without closing it, like the kernel restart function that exists in the notebook. I tried `%reset` but that doesn't seem to clear the imports.

Comment: For me it seems to clear also imports (ipython 2.2, macosx): 

In [1]: %whos
Interactive namespace is empty.

In [2]: import os

In [3]: %whos
Variable   Type      Data/Info
------------------------------
os         module    <module 'os' from '/usr/l<...>.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>

In [4]: %reset
Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y

In [5]: %whos
Interactive namespace is empty.

Comment: Yes the namespace is cleared, but when re-importing it seems to read a cached version of the module, so I have to use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module.

Comment: Ah ok I see. You could also use http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html. But I understand this is not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Call/duplicate the "kernel restart function that exists in the notebook"?

Comment: I do it all the time. The shortcut is Ctrl-'.' [ctrl-period]. Just tested on Linux and it only works in qtconsole.

Answer (score 15):

Even though it would be handy if `%reset` would clear the namespace and the cache for the imports (as in the notebook) one can explicitly reload a previously imported module using `importlib.reload` in python3.4 or `imp.reload` in python3.0-3.3  (and if needed reset the kernel in a second step).

Answer (score 7):

I could restart the kernel, but some console sessions take longer to reconnect. Notebook detects kernel restart instantly.

`ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel` class has a `do_shutdown` method with `restart` parameter which defaults to `False`.

Get a reference to `ipykernel.kernelapp.IPKernelApp` which has a reference to the kernel and call `do_shutdown` of the kernel by passing `True`.

```
import IPython
app = IPython.Application.instance()
app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)
```

How did I test?

```
$ #start notebook
$ jupyter notebook

$ #connect to existing kernel
$ jupyter console --existing
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed Spyder with anaconda, then open Spyder window.

Then Consoles (menu bar) -> Restart Consoles.

or you can use CTRL+. which is a shortcut key to restart the console.

Answer (score 3):

I personaly use add these two lines at the top of each ipynb file in JupyterLab:

```
load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

It allows you to update the code in an adjacent xxx.py file, without having to restart the Kernel, which was a huge painpoint for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the qt console you could hit `ctrl-`

Answer (score 0):

IPython Qt-console has a reset kernel  feature. You could use that if you are using IPython Qt. IMO it is better than using from the shell.

[image]

Answer (score -6):

In 3.7 Anaconda, just go to Kernel, select Restart

[image]

Comment: nice camera shots 镜头 ~