# "No Module named sqlalchemy" after having just installed it from IPython prompt

Tags: python, python-3.4

[image: screenshot]

I am unable to import sqlalchemy. I searched and found few solutions like installing flask or flask_sqlalchemy etc. None of these helped.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `pip --version` what does it say? You might have to use `pip3` instead.

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4). I did try pip3 as well. No luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to restart `ipython` for it to find freshly-installed modules.

I believe this holds for modules that add to `sys.path`.

---

As per [Can I zip all the python standard libs and the python still able to import it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969136/can-i-zip-all-the-python-standard-libs-and-the-python-still-able-to-import-it/46970267#46970267) , `site.main()` should work, too.

It, among other things, scans `site-packages` directories for `.pth` files and adds their contents to `sys.path`. Thanks to the fact that its logic checks for duplicates before adding, it shouldn't clutter `sys.path` when invoked repeatedly.

Comment: actually restarting the kernel within ipython took care of it. Thanks!

Comment: @ArvindKandaswamy how do you do that? I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603456/reset-ipython-kernel but it has no definite answer.

Comment: I did it within jupyter by selecting kernel->restart from the jupyter menu.