# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy' after installation in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pip, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I have installed sqlalchemy in venv. It works in VSCode but I need to use it in Jupyter Notebook and is not working. When I attempt to install it in the notebook a message is shown saying the requirement has already been satisfied.
I have installed flask-sqlalchemy as I saw some people advised but this one is not recognized too.
I have also restarted the kernel but it did not work.[image]

Comment: I think your question is duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494172/no-module-named-sqlalchemy-after-having-just-installed-it-from-ipython-prompt)

Comment: I suppose it is, i did not see this one when I searched for an answer. But the proposed solution does not work for me. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally run it but I had to install ipykernel in the virtual environment:

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user
```