# Is it possible to restart the Ipython kernel without exiting?

Tags: python, ipython, miniconda

I am using Miniconda, and want to restart the Kernel so that it starts from In[1] again.

Ctrl+ or Ctrl- is not working.
%reset is just flushing out the memory.

Is it possible to fully flush the memory and restart the kernel from the beginning without exiting from the existing session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset ipython kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603456/reset-ipython-kernel)